# Javascript getElement - what happens behind the scene?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know what goes on in the backstage when you call document.getElementById/TagName/className etc.
Is there some regex involved? Like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName = function (tag) {
    var pattern = new RegExp("<"+tag+" .*<\/"+tag+">", "gi");
    return this.content.match(pattern);
}
```

Or there is some more fancy stuff going on?

Thanks

Comment: The browser implements the DOM methods.  There is no regex magic going on.  It's processing a tree structure, not a raw string.

Comment: Also, you should *never* use regex to match HTML.

Comment: Do you know how instances in OOP and tree data structures work?